# How to add dependencies in eclipse in android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an old android project which use eclipse ,

The  following code is for gradle on https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment

```
dependencies {
    // your other dependencies...
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0'
}
```

I hope to add the dependencies to my old project in eclipse, how can I do ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation:

Create a "lib" folder and keep all your jars in the folder.

Subsequently, add all the jar files in the lib folder into your build path by using `Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add JAR` ...

Comment: Thanks! but there is not any jar file, only a URL  'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0' is provide

Comment: @HelloCW  if you need only jar file, then why don't you download it from gradle/maven repositories.